# how to open popup window using jsp or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In my Program have one hiperlink ..

when we click hiperlink a small popup will open and ask name and this name sending using form.

So how to create popup using jsp or javascript or jquery?

Comment: And what do you have for now?

Comment: You can do that using `window.open()`. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use window.open for this

```
window.open("page url",null,
"height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

have a look at this link..
[window.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That..was.. brave! Quoting Microsoft dev network instead of Mozilla's :)

Answer (score 7):

The following JavaScript will open a new browser window, 450px wide by 300px high with scrollbars:

```
window.open("http://myurl", "_blank", "scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=300,width=450");
```

You can add this to a link like so:

```
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:window.open("http://myurl", "_blank", "scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=300,width=450");' title='Pop Up'>Pop Up</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<a href="javaScript:{openPopUp();}"></a>
<form action="actionName">
<div id="divId" style="display:none;">
UsreName:<input type="text" name="userName"/>
</div>
</form>

function openPopUp()
{
  $('#divId').css('display','block');
$('#divId').dialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**SCRIPT:**

```
function winOpen()
{
    window.open("yourpage.jsp");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="winOpen()">Pop Up</a>
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open for `window.open`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with in jquery-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    //your form layout
    </div>
```